# Strapi v4: How to access context within a service

Tags: javascript, next.js, strapi

When I create a custom controller in Strapi I get convenient access to a Context object where I can get the current user and use that user's data as I wish:

```
module.exports = createCoreController("api::event.event", ({ strapi }) => ({
  //Get logged in  users
  async me(ctx) {
    const user = ctx.state.user;

    if (!user) {
      return ctx.badRequest(null, [
        { messages: [{ id: "No authorization header was found" }] },
      ]);
    }
    const data = await strapi.entityService.findMany("api::event.event", {
      filters: {
        user: user.id,
      },
    });

    if (!data) {
      return ctx.notFound();
    }

    const sanitizedEntity = await sanitize.contentAPI.output(data);

    return { data: sanitizedEntity };
  },
}));
```

However when I create a custom service by trying to extend the Core services, I don't seem to have the context object as above:

```
module.exports = createCoreService("api::event.event", ({ strapi }) => ({
  //https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization/services.html#extending-core-services

  async create(params) {
    console.log("inside event.js - create");
    console.log("params", params);

    console.log("params to save", params);

    // some logic here
    const result = await super.create(params);
    // some more logic

    return result;
  },

  async update(entityId, params) {
    params.data.user = entityId;

    // some logic here
    const result = await super.update(entityId, params);
    // some more logic

    return result;
  },
}));
```

If possible I would like to access the context object because I would like to access the user info and get user id and add that id as the owner or creator of that entry.

Is it possible and how does one do that???

Answer (score 1):

**Service methods are just like normal functions** you can define parameters when you create a Service method.
In my case my Service method name is `customServiceMethod`.
you just have to call the `customServiceMethod` inside you controller & pass the `ctx`(context) to it.
in the controller file:

```
/**
 * vehicle-post controller
 */

import { factories } from "@strapi/strapi";

export default factories.createCoreController(
  "api::vehicle-post.vehicle-post",
  {
    async create(ctx) {
      return await strapi
                   .services["api::vehicle-post.vehicle-post"]
                   .customServiceMethod(ctx);

    },
  }
);
```

then in the Service file:

```
module.exports = ({ strapi }: { strapi: Strapi }) => ({
  async customServiceMethod(context) {
  // ctx will be accessible here using context parameter we defined.
  console.log(context);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case others Strapi's users reaches this post, there's now an other way to achieve this :

```
module.exports = createCoreService("api::event.event", ({ strapi }) => ({
 myService() {
    const ctx = strapi.requestContext.get();
    // Do some stuff
  },
}));
```

It's well explained in the docs : https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/backend-customization/requests-responses#accessing-the-request-context-anywhere